# url scheme safari

Tags: javascript, react, ios, safari

Quero abrir um link específicamente no safari, qual seria a url scheme do safari ?

Tente com:

```
 window.open(`com-apple-mobilesafari-tab:https://meusite.ao/?a`, '_blank', 'popup');
```

Infelizmente não deu certo

Comment: Algum motivo em especial de querer forçar que a página seja aberta no Safari, ignorando a preferência do usuário?

Comment: [Essa pergunta já foi feita anteriormente](/q/587033/70) - para evitar duplicação de orientações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado nessa postagem, mas está disponível na pergunta original. Você pode editar a original, que automaticamente ela é destacada para uma reavaliação.